# Javascript: Arrays, For-Loops and Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have this working code but am not sure how to create a proper loop.

Looking for a way to create a function where one mousesovers an #id in a list element and doing so changes the url source of #mainImage to the one in the imgUrl array.

using forEach seems like a good option and am having problems setting it up.

```js
var imgUrl = [];
imgUrl[0] = "url 1";
imgUrl[1] = "url 2";
imgUrl[2] = "url 3";
imgUrl[3] = "url 4";
imgUrl[4] = "url 5";
imgUrl[5] = "url 6";
imgUrl[6] = "url 7";


(document).ready(function() {

  // mouse over ids in list
  $("#id-1").mouseover(function() {
    $("#mainImage").attr("src", imgUrl[0])
  });

  //mouse over 2
  $("#id-2").mouseover(function() {
    $("#mainImage").attr("src", imgUrl[1])
  });

  //mouse over 3
  $("#id-3").mouseover(function() {
    $("#mainImage").attr("src", imgUrl[2])
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img id="mainImage" src="url">
</div>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="id-1">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-2">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-3">three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-4">four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-5">five</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-6">six</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-7">seven</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `forEach`, it would be more elegant to use only *one* listener (on the `ul`) and check the `event.target` (the hovered element)'s index in the list, and access the same index in the `imgUrl` array. No jQuery needed for plain DOM manipulation:

```js
const imgUrl = [];
imgUrl[0] = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/56a79d2067e203926e68dae37adbea58?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
imgUrl[1] = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/34932d3e923ffad9a4a1423e30b1d9fc?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";
imgUrl[2] = "url 3";
imgUrl[3] = "url 4";
imgUrl[4] = "url 5";
imgUrl[5] = "url 6";
imgUrl[6] = "url 7";

const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const mainImage = document.querySelector('#mainImage');
menu.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'A') return;
  const index = [...menu.children].indexOf(e.target.parentElement);
  mainImage.src = imgUrl[index];
});
```

```html
  <img id="mainImage" src="url">
</div>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="id-1">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-2">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-3">three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-4">four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-5">five</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-6">six</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="id-7">seven</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome code!

What does 'A' mean in the if statement?

Comment: The `tagName` - it checks to see if the hovered element is an `<a>`.

Comment: `menu.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {`

e is the parameter?

Comment: `e` is the event. See [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) It's the same parameter that jQuery handlers get

Answer (score 0):

You can add listeners in a loop

```js
 var urls = ['url1', url2', 'url3', 'url4','url5', 'url6']
 Array.from(Array(6)).forEach((_, index) => {
  $("#id-"+ (index + 1)).mouseover(() => $("#mainImage").attr("src", urls[index]));
 });
```

Comment: Thanks!! I am new to javascript. Will learn more about listeners